# How to use Midiutil to add multiple notes in one timespot (or how to add chords)

Tags: python, midi

I am using Midiutil to recreate a modified Bach contrapuntist melody and I am having difficulty finding a method for creating chords using Midiutil in python. Does anyone know a way to create chords using Midiuitl or if there is a way to create chords.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chord consists of multiple notes.

Just add multiple notes with the same timestamp.